# Python Paramiko Sudo Command

Tags: python, stdout, stdin, sudo, paramiko

```
    client paramiko.SSHClient() 
    client set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) 
    client.connect()
    stdin stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("sudo passwd root")
```

I've got a question!!!!!
I have to change password for each of my VMs. Some of the accounts for logging into Vms don't have to stdin.write password for using sudo command and some of the accounts have to input their password.
How can i detect the need for stdin for executing sudo command???

Expecting there will be a fuction for stdin, but i can't find any method for that?
And i've tried to print stdout, and it get stucked (I guess is the buffer issue for infinite loop)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like [`paramiko-expect`](https://github.com/fgimian/paramiko-expect). Establish the SSH connection, then you can `.expect` the "password for" prompt.

If you receive a "password for" prompt, then send the sudo password. If you do not (and it appears that you will have to try-except a `TimeoutError` (or similar) to determine if you do not receive the sudo prompt, you just continue with changing the password.

However: I think you're using the wrong tool here. I think something like Ansible [with the user module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html) is a better solution than trying to rig something over SSH.

Comment: Actually there's other use case for using sudo command, i just want to check whether password needed or not when using sudo???